# Changing a column value in whole rows in datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I try to change a column value in all rows in datatable and show datatable in datagridview but nothing show in datagridview here is the source code that I use please help me

```
      DataTable d = new DataTable();
      d = DataPortAction.GetCustomerHostById(CustomerId);
      foreach (DataRow ro in d.Rows)
      {
          DateTime dt1 = new DateTime();
          dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(ro[2]);
         ro[2] = (PersianDate)dt1;

      }
      dataGridView1.DataSource = d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try calling before binging to grid.

```
d.AcceptChanges();
```